# How to pass strings that may be encoded multiple times

Tags: json, encoding, decode, dataformat

I need to pass data around that can be encoded in multiple data formats. For instance I have json that includes a bash script to be run. This json data may be passed around back and forth through multiple services and I need to make sure that they don't get double escaped. Additionally, this bash script may contain a json input as well (e.g. Json -> Bash -> Json)

I was thinking that perhaps I could include something that states how each piece of of data should be encoded and decoded. Then fully encode and decode it every time it passes through a service. However, that seems clumsy, brittle and likely to have performance issues.

Any other ideas?

Here is an example of what the input might look like:

```json
{
  "bash-script": "echo '{\\\"foo\\\": \\\"bar\\\"}'"
}
```

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: In general, I would suggest you should do Json -> unescaped -> ecaped(bash) -> unescaped -> escaped(Json), i.e. each time you receive data from a source, you convert it to back its "original" unescaped data, then re-escape it as necessary for the next target in the chain. If you have a case where this isn't possible, it would be interesting to see that case. This can happen, e.g. when a file claims to be in one encoding but is actually encoded differently, or where the assumed default is wrong... in which case, your problem is you need to detect and fix up those specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep unescaping while the JSON is valid, since a valid JSON is not a valid bash script except for one single command surrounded by string.

```py
def unescape_all(s):
    while True:
        try:
            s = json.loads(s)
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            return s
```

Example

```py
codes = ['echo "Hello world"', 
        '"echo \\"Hello world\\""', 
        '"\\"echo \\\\\\"Hello world\\\\\\"\\""', 
        '"\\"\\\\\\"echo \\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Hello world\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\"\\""']
print([unescape_all(s) for s in codes])
```

and you see

```
['echo "Hello world"', 'echo "Hello world"', 'echo "Hello world"', 'echo "Hello world"']
```